# Drools - Changing the Java compiler level

Tags: jboss, drools, rule-engine

I want to change the java compiler level to 1.6 but it doesn't seem to work for me. I am trying to use generics in the consequence part.

Following is my code that I used to change the compiler level.

**Drools Version: 5.2.1 GA**
**JDK Version : 1.6**

```
final Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("drools.dialect.java.compiler", "JANINO");
properties.setProperty("drools.dialect.default", "java");
properties.setProperty("drools.compiler.lnglevel", "1.6");


PackageBuilderConfiguration packageBuilderConfiguration =
      new PackageBuilderConfiguration(properties,(ClassLoader[]) null);

final KnowledgeBuilder knowledgeBuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory
                .newKnowledgeBuilder(packageBuilderConfiguration);
```

Let me know where I am going wrong.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Janino intentionally does not support generics. It appears to be a conscious decision, so there's not likely to be a change in that with new versions. They're also not going to support the enhanced for() loop and enums, both of which I've also grown to miss in Drools.

Check out the [Janino webpage](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home), near the bottom right in what they do not support.

If you take out the "JANINO" line from your example, I'd be curious if you could start using them.  (The default compiler is the eclipse compiler, at least it was the last time I checked.

Comment: According to http://janino-compiler.github.io/janino/ it now supports the enhanced for loop, and some support for enums.